# PiCloud-like service on Azure?

Tags: azure

I'm looking for an execution environment on Windows Azure that is similar to PiCloud:

1. queued jobs
2. CPU charged in small increments (1ms in case of PiCloud)

Does anyone know of such a service?

Answer (score 1):

Not off hand. Windows Azure is more like Amazon in that you get a dedicated VM with per hour pricing. I don't believe anyone has yet created a multi-tenant job processing framework on it with he ability to bill-back the time spent working on client jobs.

Sound like an interesting idea for a start-up though. :)